# how to add button in UIAlertController In IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertcontroller

how we use `UIAlertView` in iOS 9 and how to add button in `UIAlertController`

```
UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController 

alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Yes, please"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                            **//What we write here????????**


                        }];
UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               **//What we write here????????**

                           }];

[alert addAction:yesButton];
[alert addAction:noButton];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: already u added the two buttons , in that **//What we write here????????**, you need to handle your action whatever u need , thats all bro, u need to add more buttons..

Comment: then how to handle that action??? i can't understand  :( @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                              message:@"Message"
                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes, please"
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
{
    /** What we write here???????? **/
    NSLog(@"you pressed Yes, please button");

    // call method whatever u need
}];

UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks"
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
{
    /** What we write here???????? **/
    NSLog(@"you pressed No, thanks button");
    // call method whatever u need
}];

[alert addAction:yesButton];
[alert addAction:noButton];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**swift**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let yesButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, please", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        /** What we write here???????? **/
        print("you pressed Yes, please button")
        // call method whatever u need
    })
    let noButton = UIAlertAction(title: "No, thanks", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        /** What we write here???????? **/
        print("you pressed No, thanks button")
        // call method whatever u need
    })
    alert.addAction(yesButton)
    alert.addAction(noButton)
    present(alert, animated: true) { _ in }
```

Comment: initially press the button put the break point and check , the NSlog will called , in here no need of any delegates on UIAlertcontroller, if are you using alertview , the delegates will called and we handle the further procedure but in UIAlertController no need of delegate method, the UIAlertaction is handle the delegate action of every buttons.

Comment: @anupgupta -- happy to hear this bro, initially I also faced this probem , day by day I learned myself just like how you are doing ....

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, My UIAlertController is global variable because I've progress bar on it and updating it but problem is while clicking on UIAlertAction button it crash.

Answer (score 5):

You actually need to write code after ok and cancel button pressed in their respective completion blocks.

```
UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController 

alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Yes, please"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                            [self okButtonPressed];

                        }];
   UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               [self cancelButtonPressed];

                           }];

   [alert addAction:yesButton];
   [alert addAction:noButton];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


 - (void)cancelButtonPressed{
     // write your implementation for cancel button here.
}

 - (void)okButtonPressed{
    //write your implementation for ok button here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks bro @anupgupta

Answer (score 0):

You can just leave these blocks `nil` if you're not needed any additional actions after the button tapping:

```
UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Yes, please"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:nil];
```