# alerting user to push when app is open

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, uialertcontroller

my appDelegate has a the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let dictPayload = userInfo as NSDictionary

    if let data = dictPayload.value(forKey: "aps") as? NSDictionary {
        let link = data.value(forKey: "Link") as? String
        print("link: \(link!)")


        UserDefaults.standard.set(link, forKey: "link_from_push")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        UserDefaults.standard.set("open_link", forKey: "push_action")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    print("Push notification received: \(userInfo)")
}
```

I can see the flow of information through Xcode. Now I want to pop an alert if app is open and in the foreground, no matter which view the user is on at the moment.

the following function is used from appDelegate:

```
    let topWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
topWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "APNS", message: "received  Notification", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "confirm"), style: .cancel, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
// continue your work
// important to hide the window after work completed.
// this also keeps a reference to the window until the action is invoked.
topWindow.isHidden = true
}))
topWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
topWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: { _    in })
```

Which works fine but I need to add another action button.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155769/how-to-show-uialertcontroller-from-appdelegate/36156077#36156077

Comment: thanks.  I will be deleting this question since it is a duplicate. I should have searched better before asking. sorry

Comment: not like , ....