# iOS popup message in app delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uialertcontroller

I tried to create a pop-up alert message in my app delegate but it's not showing up at all. The program is written is Swift 4.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156077/7576100)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show UIAlertController from Appdelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155769/how-to-show-uialertcontroller-from-appdelegate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `didFinishLaunching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc.):

> Tells the delegate that the launch process is **almost done** and the app is **almost ready** to run.

So I don't think you can show an alert in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Try to move your code to `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: yeah moved my pop-up message in appdelgate swift file to func applicationDidBecomeActive. The pop-up started working with no problem. Thanks for catching the error...

Answer (score -1):

If there’s one rule to remember in iOS native programming, it is this: UI components can only be properly manipulated on main thread. Keep this in mind and I’m sure it will spare you from headaches in the future.

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let actionYes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { action in
        print("Handler YES")
    })

    let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
        print("Handler CANCEL")
    })

    alert.addAction(actionYes)
    alert.addAction(actionCancel)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```