# Objective-C - UIAlertView doesn't delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have this code, I'm trying to get a language selector on an Alert View, but I think that the delegate is not working.

```
@interface JumboEntranceViewController () <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, WSLoginDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
...
...
...
...

- (void) showLanguageSelector {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Idioma" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"English",@"Español",@"Deustch", nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0) { //CANCEL
        [[LanguagesManager sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"es"];
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        [[LanguagesManager sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"en"];
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 2) {
        [[LanguagesManager sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"es"];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
        [[LanguagesManager sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"de"];
    }
}
```

But I cannot not get into the function *didDismissWithButtonIndex*

Comment: UIAlertview is deprecated use [UIAlertcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152650/how-to-add-button-in-uialertcontroller-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code. (UIAlertView is deprecated since iOS 9.0.)

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Idioma" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"English" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [[LanguagesManager sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"en"];
    }]];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Español" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [[LanguagesManager sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"es"];
    }]];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Deustch" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [[LanguagesManager sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"de"];
    }]];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [[LanguagesManager sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"es"];
    }]];

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the actions are not called @SargisGevorgyan

Answer (score -1):

First of all, as mentioned in comments UIAlertView is deprecated since iOS 9.0. You should use UIAlertController instead, just like Xcode tells you with warnings both in the implementation of UIAlertView and of the delegate method

Anyway, I implemented an exact copy of your code and it works: are you sure the issue isn't in the LanguageManager singleton instead? Did you try putting a breakpoint in the first line of alertview:didDismissWithButtonIndex: to see if it gets called?

[edit] To clarify, following is the code, [and here's the proof it works](https://streamable.com/zdt3u):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Idioma"
                                                    message:@"" 
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"English",@"Español",@"Deustch", nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];
}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0) { //CANCEL
        NSLog(@"0");
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"1");
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
        NSLog(@"3");
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: it doesn't get called

Comment: But I can assure you it does. I replaced the calls to the singleton with NSLogs, I just tested it and it logs as expected. But anyway, follow the other suggestion because you should never implement deprecated code if you aren't really forced to do so